# How to disable additional app permissions?

Tags: permissions

Some apps have annoying permissions like installing shortcut on the homescreen (everytime u open it). How do I disable these permissions? (see picture)

[image]

Comment: Speaking explicitly of "installing shortcut", if you are rooted, you can just go disable a corresponding broadcast receiver so no apps can put a shortcut on that launcher anymore.

Comment: How do I disable a corresponding broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [NoAutoShortcut](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.crossbowffs.noautoshortcut) if your phone/tablet is rooted and Xposed framework installed. It is an Xposed module that prevent apps from creating shortcuts.

Comment: I think Xposed doesn't work on 7.0+

Comment: @AeroWindwalker I dont know about 8 but for Android 7 it does. You can read and check links for downloads [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/official-xposed-framework-android-nougat/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [App Permission Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.permission&hl=en) available on Google market. It pretty much handles permissions with ability to overriding them.

Comment: That app only works on KitKat. Any suggestions for later versions ?